# Easy fix - sorting a deque on multiple values

Tags: c++, sorting, deque

I'm trying to figure out how to sort a deque of structs on two values, not just one.  The code I have is what I have which perfectly sorts on `arrival`, but if two items came in with the same `pid`, I'd like them to be in pid order as well.  I hope I'm making sense!

For example:

A process that has a `pid` of 1 and an `arrival` of 10 should be before a process with `pid` of 2 with an `arrival` of 10, even if the process with `pid` 1 comes later in the deque originally.

```
struct Process{
    int pid;
    int burst;
    int arrival;
};

int sortOnArrival (Process const &a, Process const &b){
    return a.arrival < b.arrival;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    deque<Process> readyQueue;

    // This is just pseudocode, but trust me, it works. :)
    fill(readyQueue);

    sort(readyQueue.begin(), readyQueue.end(), sortOnArrival);
}
```

Comment: It isn't clear from your question whether you meant for `pid` or `arrival` to have higher priority in the comparison. Examine the answers closely, as there is disagreement that point.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a suitable comparison object. For example, you could use

```
struct sortOnPidAndArrival {
    bool operator()(Process const& p0, Process const& p1) const {
        return std::tie(p0.pid, p0.arrival) < std::tie(p1.pid, p1.arrival);
    }
};
```

In case you wonder why I'm using a function object rather than a function pointer: The code in this function object can entirely be inlined. The call through a function pointer cannot.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that `std::tie` is C++-only.

Comment: Well, `std::tie()` is part of standard C++. If you are using a system which isn't implementing the current standard but some earlier one, you are right, it isn't there. The use of `std::tie()` isn't really required but nice arranges for a lexicographical order on two variables. It can be formulated explicitly but, especially with more variables, it is actually a point to get right.

Comment: Errr. I meant C++-**11** only, which you correctly inferred. And yes, using `std::tie` is to be preferred to building the comparison by hand.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I'm not aware of any complete implementation of the C++ standard (neither C++ 2003 nor C++ 2011 although you can put together a C++ 2003 implementation by using the correct compiler with the correct standard library implementation) or any implementation claiming to be complete. However, it is still the current standard. I guess, my comment was lacking a smiley somewhere to indicate that I didn't mean it entirely serious...

Answer (score 3):

Your comparison function needs to consider all requirements for the comparison.

```
int sortOnArrival (Process const &a, Process const &b) {
    if( a.arrival == b.arrival ) return a.pid < b.pid;
    return a.arrival < b.arrival;
}
```